# serialization of a value from two models with links to foreign key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

A have three models:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    some_field = models.ForeignKey(ModelB)

class ModelC(models.Model):
    some_field = models.ForeignKey(ModelB)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    first_field = models.CharField()
    second_field = models.CharField()
```

I want serialize ModelA and get value from ModelC. How can you do it?

```
class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ('id', 'some_field', 'here_is_value_from_ModelC'???)
```

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#reverse-relations 

check this one

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get fields of modelC from modelA serializer then this code will works.

```
class ModelCserializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelC
        fields = ('some_field',)

class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    here_is_value_from_ModelC= ModelCserializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ('id', 'some_field', 'here_is_value_from_ModelC')
```

or

```
class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    some_field= serializer.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ('id', 'some_field', 'some_field')
```

Comment: Please explain why you think what you are doing is correct and how it works.